# prevent Exception exception thrown by EF core when trying to delete but it has restrict constraint

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

a have an API controller,
and I am having trouble with restricting constraint.
I will specify below.

My code look like this:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveFunkce([FromRoute] int id)
{
    await _context.Funkce.Where(f => f.Id == id).DeleteAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

The problem is that the "Funkce" table has a foreign key to users, which has restrict constraint, which prevents me from deleting it if some user references to the row in the "Funkce" table. But if I try to delete the row and it's restricted by the constraint the controller that I showed you earlier will result in "500 Internal Server Error", which I don't want to happen.

I have successfully try catch it, it looks like this:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveFunkce([FromRoute] int id)
{
  try
  {
    await _context.Funkce.Where(f => f.Id == id).DeleteAsync();
    return Ok();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    if (await _context.Users.Where(f => f.FunkceId == id).AnyAsync())
      return Conflict(new { Error = "Funkce je používána" });
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

But I don't want to use "try-catch" to threat the thrown exception instead, I would like to prevent it from ever happening and resolve the error my self is there a way to do this? some event or whatever? If not, I would like if you don't know some nice list of exceptions thrown by the EF core if I find one I will share it below :) Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't tell EF do not throw exception when operation you trying to execute fails.

You should either do not even start this operation (for example, search for child records before calling Delete), or use try-catch.

Searching for child records require you to make SELECT's to all linked tables, so you will need to put this code in all you action methods, and this is not very good. But you have no other way.